# How desirable are features like Cryptonote in an altcoin?

Tags: altcoin

How desirable are features like  Cryptonote in an altcoin?
DO you guys think, this is a feature you guys would prefer over an X11 or X13 algorihm?

Comment: Opinion-based questions like this are not a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's the technology itself. Among other features we can see the actually untraceable payments and unlinkable transactions which are executed via ring signatures. Greg Maxwell who is one of the Bitcoin fore-founders wrote that it would be good to implement such a mechanism in Bitcoin itself.

There's ASIC resistant and egalitarian PoW algo. This means the efficiency of mining is the same for CPU and GPU. Also there's a mechanism on protocol level which allows the users to vote for all changes through hashrate. Here's detailed info https://cryptonote.org/inside.php.

The protocol is entirely different from the one used by Bitcoin and is made on a different base. It must have been made by a team of extremely skilled scientists.

Secondly the Cryptonote technology has survived the test of time. The initial version of the Cryptonote whitepaper appeared at the end of 2012 https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper_v1.pdf. Its first implementation named Bytecoin was launched a bit earlier and it's still stable.

Comment: Just a small comment to correct an inaccuracy: Cryptonote did not appear in 2012. There was an apparent attempt to "whitewash" a huge premine in bytecoin. See the investigation in https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=740112.0 for details.